End-to-end numeration of exercises in book
I want to do end-to-end numeration for exercises in LaTeX. The solution that I found:
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First exercise
  \item Second exercise
\end{enumerate}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\begin{enumerate}[resume] % continue the numbering from the last enumerate
  \item Third exercise
  \item Fourth exercise
\end{enumerate}

doesn't work fully. I mean it works when I only use enumerate for exercise but what if I want to use enumerate for other stuff. For example I want to write something like this:


Exercise 1
Exercise 2

Now I want to mention three cases:

Case 1
Case 2
Case 3

Let's continue our exercises:

Exercise 3
Exercise 4

...

If it matters I use the book type of the document.

You should look at the docs of enumitem. There is an option series=... where you can give your type of lists a name. For instance, for the first enumerate in exercises: series=myexercise. For subsequent enumerate in exercises: resume*=myexercise.

Set your "end-to-end enumeration" as a series, which you can then resume at any time.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Global list

% Set first enumeration as "global"
\begin{enumerate}[series=global]
  \item First exercise
  \item Second exercise
\end{enumerate}

Second (case) list

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Case 1
  \item Case 2
  \item Case 3
\end{enumerate}

Resume original (global) list

% Continue the numbering from the last global enumerate
\begin{enumerate}[resume=global]
  \item Third exercise
  \item Fourth exercise
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

